# js div overlay not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this div that overlays images to color them blue when you mouseover. Works nicely! Except - it doesn't seem to work in IE at all.

Any ideas?

The js
http://www.rollinleonard.com/elements/overlaymouseover.js

The page
http://www.rollinleonard.com/elements

Thanks!

Comment: did you add z-index to the div?

Comment: By the way, that's an interesting page you got there!

Comment: Thanks! I'm an artist and not a web developer (obviously). This is my attempt at doing my own site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't yet support rgba. IE9 beta does. In your case, since you don't have any text on the overlay, you don't need to set background opacity. Just set regular opacity on your #overlay.

```
#overlay{
   ...
   background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
   -moz-opacity:.60; filter:alpha(opacity=60); opacity:.60;
   ...
}
```

- http://davidwalsh.name/css-opacity
- http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

**Update**: Like you mentioned, the clicks don't go through to the links. One approach is to add a handler to the overlay, copying the underlying link.

```
  $(window).load(function(){
      var $overlay = $('#overlay');     
      $('img').bind('mouseenter', function () {
          var $this = $(this);
          if ($this.not('.over')) {
              $this.addClass('over');
              $overlay.css({
                  width  : $this.css('width'),
                  height : $this.css('height'), 
                  top    : $this.offset().top + 'px',
                  left   : $this.offset().left + 'px',
              }).show();
              // This is hacked up,could be better, but works, it replaces the handler
              // everytime you display it
              $overlay.onclick = function() {
                   location.href = $this.getAttribute('href');
              }
          }
       }).bind('mouseout', function () {
           $(this).removeClass('over');
       });
  });
```

Comment: @Juan Thanks! That was helpful. I see that I just need to make the background-color 0000ff and it works. Except, IE doesn't allow me to click through the div now. http://www.rollinleonard.com/elements/index2.php

Comment: That's because your pointer-events CSS property is also not supported by IE. Therefore, your div is covering your links and they are not receiving clicks

Comment: @Juan .... darn. Is there a way to click through a div in IE? I see that now. Not supported.

Comment: @Rollin, uhhhhh... I suggested a workaround... did you try it? Also, please fix your indentation, badly indented code is usually a sign of carelessness.

Comment: @Juan - it would be better to set a custom data attribute with the link href on the overlay. And have a single callback that reads the data attribute to redirect.

Comment: @Juan Oh shoot! I didn't see that. I updated it with your code but it doesn't behave as I expected. I am going to fix the indentation as well.

Edit: It doesn't seem like there is a href on the div in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Use keyword var to declare your variables:

instead of:

```
$overlay = $('#overlay');
```

Use:

```
var $overlay = $('#overlay');
```

Same thing with `$this = $(this);`

**Update --**

Not sure what I was thinking.

As long as you are making an assignment your javascript is valid, however the error in IE is coming from line 15 of overlaymouseover.js:

```
left   : $this.offset().left + 'px', // extra comma breaks IE
```

And that is your problem.

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to answer the question, does it? Sure, it's bad practice, but that's not what's causing the problem.

Comment: not using 'var' only makes the variable global (bad practice)

Comment: @Juan Mendes, @ josh.trow - thanks for the comments guys. See my update.

Comment: @Josiah. What you said is true, except that IE8, like other browsers, now accepts a trailing comma when defining an object. At first I was baffled that I didn't notice it, that was because IE didn't throw an error.

Comment: @josiah Thanks for showing me that! I didn't know that about not using "var" making it global. It appears that even with the misplaced comma (I've removed it) it doesn't turn blue in IE. rgba doesn't work in IE as Juan pointed out. Now my only problem is that I can't click through the div in IE...

Comment: @Juan - yep stuck on IE7 at work. I couldn't get past the error to test any further. Seems that your solutions will work. You should still remove that trailing comma however.